# How to create an alert in your Data Model, and call it in your ViewController as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alerts

Currently I'm trying to add an alert in the model Class. I add ViewController as a parameter so do

```
viewController.present(alertView, animated: true)
```

It looks something like

```
class DataClass { 
    func addAlert(viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let message = message {
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) 
            alertView.addAction(okAction)

            viewController.present(alertView, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

And then in my ViewController

```
class mainVC: UIViewController {
    var mainVCVar: mainVC?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addAlert(viewController: mainVCVar) 
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

> unexpectedly returned nil.

Is it possible to call my own View Controller in the same View Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a different view controller than the one you are calling the function from.  It is nil because that view controller is not instantiated.

Do this instead:

```
addAlert(viewController: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need a DataClass object.
second, you need to present the alert on the current view controller, which Is self

```
class mainVC: UIViewController {
    var mainVCVar: mainVC?
    var dataClass = DataClass()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataClass.addAlert(viewController: self)
    }
}
```